# Replace values in Pandas Dataframe using another Dataframe as a lookup table

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dataframe

I'm looking to replace values in a Dataframe with the values in a second Dataframe by matching the values in the first Dataframe with the columns from the second Dataframe.

Example:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
dt_index = pd.to_datetime(['2003-05-01', '2003-05-02', '2003-05-03', '2003-05-04'])
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,1,3,12], 'B':[12,1,3,3], 'C':[3,12,12,1]}, index = dt_index)
df2 = pd.DataFrame({1:[1.4,4.2,1.3,5.6], 12:[2.3,7.3,9.5,0.4], 3:[8.8,0.1,8.7,2.4], 4:[9.6,9.8,5.5,1.8]}, index = dt_index)
```

```
df =             
             A   B   C
2003-05-01   1  12   3
2003-05-02   1   1  12
2003-05-03   3   3  12
2003-05-04  12   3   1

df2 = 
             1    12   3    4 
2003-05-01  1.4  2.3  8.8  9.6
2003-05-02  4.2  7.3  0.1  9.8
2003-05-03  1.3  9.5  8.7  5.5
2003-05-04  5.6  0.4  2.4  1.8
```

Expected output:

```
expect = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1.4,4.2,8.7,0.4], 'B':[2.3,4.2,8.7,2.4], 'C':[8.8,7.3,9.5,5.6]}, index = dt_index)
```

```
expect = 
              A    B    C
2003-05-01  1.4  2.3  8.8
2003-05-02  4.2  4.2  7.3
2003-05-03  8.7  8.7  9.5
2003-05-04  0.4  2.4  5.6
```

Attempt:

```
X = df.copy()
for i in np.unique(df):
    X.mask(df == i, df2[i], axis=0, inplace=True)
```

My attempt seems to work but I'm not sure if it has any pitfalls and how it would scale as the sizes of the Dataframe increase.

Are there better or faster solutions?

### EDIT:

After cottontail's helpful answer, I realised I've made an oversimplification in my example. The values in df and columns of df and df2 cannot be assumed to be sequential.

I've now modified the example to reflect that.

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to use `stack()` to reshape `df2` into a Series and `reindex()` it using the values in `df`; reshape back into original shape using `unstack()`.

```py
tmp = df2.stack().reindex(df.stack().droplevel(-1).items())
tmp.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([tmp.index.get_level_values(0), df.columns.tolist()*len(df)])
df = tmp.unstack()
```

[image: process]

Another approach is to iteratively create a dummy dataframe shaped like `df2`, multiply it by `df2`, reduce it into a Series (using `sum()`) and assign it to an empty dataframe shaped like `df`.

```py
X = pd.DataFrame().reindex_like(df)
df['dummy'] = 1

for c in X:
    X[c] = (
        df.groupby([df.index, c])['dummy'].size()
        .unstack(fill_value=0)
        .reindex(df2.columns, axis=1, fill_value=0)
        .mul(df2)
        .sum(1)
    )
```

[image: process2]

Comment: Thank you. Would this still work if the columns and values weren't sequential? e.g. [1, 2, 5, 22]?

Comment: @handlist as long as the column names in `df2` are sequential, it should work. I added another pandas version which might be more memory-efficient if the two frames are particularly large.

Comment: Sorry @cottontail, I realise now I oversimplified my problem. I've edited the question. Apologies!

Comment: @handlist did you try the second option? That one works for this case

Comment: Thank you, yes, it works well. I'm just doing some experiments on the scaling. Thanks again.

Comment: I found that for a matrix of size 1000x1000 your method is fractionally slower. Additionally, the order of the columns in the output is sorted by column name, again I didn't make this clear in my question, but column ordering must be preserved - sorry. Thanks again for having taken the time. I'm surprised that an efficient Pandas method for this doesn't already exist - it seems like a common task to me.

Comment: @handlist I added another loopy method; on my tests, this one seems faster than your implementation. Cheers.

Comment: Hmm, using Python 3.10.1 and Pandas 1.4.2, the new suggestion is over twice as slow. Could be a version or system difference. 2.5s vs 7.2s